# Is there a non-injective trace-preserving endomorphism of a matrix group?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, lie-groups

Abstractly, I'm wondering if you can have a Lie group $G$ and a non-injective homomorphism $\phi: G \to G$, and a faithful representation $\rho_G$ of $G$ which is such that $\chi_{\rho_G} = \chi_{\rho_G \circ \phi}$. The idea is that since the trace only refers to diagonal elements, I feel like you should be able to fully characterize it via it's values on a subgroup. Specifically: we know that each maximal torus $T$ of a (compact, connected) Lie group $G$ contains elements of the conjugation classes of every element of $G$, and since trace is only defined up to conjugation class, we should be able to "project" elements to representatives of their conjugation class in $T$ without losing trace information. I'm wondering if we can do so homomorphically, rather than using an algorithm like "$\chi_G (g) = {\chi_{G}}_{\upharpoonright H} (a)$ where $a \in H \subset G$ is conjugate to $g$".

But, e.g., projecting onto the diagonal, or a map $A \mapsto tr(A)I$ aren't homomorphisms, and the only type of trace-preserving homomorphism I know of is a unitary transformation, which is an isomorphism.

Can anyone give an example of such a map, or does anyone know why it's not possible if it's not? I feel like I'm missing something obvious here.

Comment: I don't know what "same character" means here. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I just mean that $\chi_G = \chi_H \circ \phi$ - that you can obtain the characters of $G$ elements by reference to $\chi_H$ via a non-injective homomorphism $\phi: G \to H$.

Comment: What is $\chi_G$? Generally speaking we take characters of representations of groups, so I don't know what you mean by taking "the" character of a group.

Comment: To make things shorter I was assuming $G$ was a matrix group, so there's an implied representation.

Comment: That doesn't make things any shorter. Mathematicians are not in the habit of implicitly assuming that Lie groups come with representations; that's why we even have an abstract theory of Lie groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the revised question: Take $G$ to be the group of strictly upper triangular matrices in $SL(n, {\mathbb R})$ (strictly here means only $1$'s on the diagonal). Now, let $\phi: G\to G$ be any endomorphism, say, the trivial representation; let $\rho_G$ be the identity representation $G\to G< GL(n, {\mathbb R})$. You can find other examples by looking at the Borel subgroup $B< SL(n, {\mathbb R})$ (the subgroup of upper triangular matrices and taking $\rho_G=Id$, $\phi$ any endomorphism equal to the identity on the maximal torus in $G$.

Comment: Yes yes thank you! Follow up question: how do you generate an endomorphism that acts as the identity on a maximal torus? (I'm assuming by *the* maximal torus you mean the subgroup of diagonal matrices?)

Comment: Also: any book recs for learning about this stuff? I've been using Bröcker & tom Dieck, which I like, but it skims over a lot of details and I don't feel like it's giving me a firm enough foundation on its own. (My background is more on the DG side than algebra.)

Comment: Oh nevermind the first comment I see now that projection to the diagonal is an endomorphism of $B$

Comment: @catbasket: Yes, this is what I had in mind. I do not know what a good reference is, I am also on the DG side. There are (too) many books on algebraic groups. For the structure theory of semisimple groups/algebras I like chapters 4-6 of Bourbaki's "Lie groups and Lie algebras". (I hardly ever read Bourbaki otherwise.)

Answer (score 0):

These things are much clearer if you make the choice of representation explicit. You have two Lie groups $G, H$ and two representations $\rho_G : G \to GL(V)$ and $\rho_H : H \to GL(W)$ of those Lie groups. You want to know if we can have a morphism $\phi : G \to H$ such that $\chi_H(\phi(g)) = \chi_G(g)$ which is not an isomorphism, or maybe not injective.

And the answer is, of course we can: given any choice of $G, H, \rho_H, W$, and $\phi$, we can take $\rho_G$ to be $\rho_G(g) = \rho_H(\phi(g))$ (so that $V = W$).

Comment: Thanks! This technically answers my question as I asked it and it's certainly helpful to reframe things in this way. However I should have specified that I'm wondering if you can do this with a faithful representation. If $\phi$ isn't injective, then $\rho_G$ as you've defined it won't be faithful.

Comment: Ok I've thought about this a bit more, and I guess what I'm looking for is this:  a faithful representation $\rho_G$ of $G$ which is such that $\chi_{\rho_G} = \chi_{\rho_G \circ \phi}$ where $\phi: G \to G$ is a non-injective homomorphism. The idea is that since you can define the character of a representation by it's action on a subgroup that contains representatives from each of its conjugacy classes, I want to know if you can do so with a homomorphism rather than an algorithm of "$\chi_G (g) = \chi_H (a)$ where $a \in H \subset G$ is conjugate to $g$".